# MVC 5 not running in hosted environment - landing page missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC & using V5.

I have Visual Studio Web Express 2013 installed on Windows 7 Home Premium.

I have created the base MVC project generated by VS. When editing the homecontroller and pressing F5 the working web site is displayed in IE.

After publishing the project to my internet provider & following the domain url a landing page missing error is displayed. There is no landing page in the solution. I also noticed the controller folders have not been published either.

I can find no reference to this deployment issue in my book. I have followed several Google'd remedies, including one Stack Overflow suggestion to add modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" into the web.config, all to no avail.

My internet provider is using ASP.NET 4.5.

I must be missing something fairly fundamental but cannot fathom out what the problem is. Suggestions Please.

Comment: You controller classes are compiled into in your bin folder. There is no problem there.

Comment: Are you compiling in a framework installed in the hosting provider?
Does the provider support MVC5?
Try to create an MVC4 webapp with fwk4.5 and deploy it and see what happens. (just a test)

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. The problem revolved around my provider and has now been sorted.